# Unable to connect email Server on JDK 8

Tags: java, email, authentication, jakarta-mail, imap

I am not able to connect IMAP mail server to fetch the mails from jdk8 but it works fine with jdk7.
Below is my code

```
private Properties getServerProperties(String protocol, String host, String port) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(String.format("mail.%s.host", protocol), host);
    properties.put(String.format("mail.%s.port", protocol), port);
    properties.setProperty(String.format("mail.%s.socketFactory.class", protocol), "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty(String.format("mail.%s.socketFactory.fallback", protocol), "false");
    properties.setProperty(String.format("mail.%s.socketFactory.port", protocol), String.valueOf(port));
    return properties;
}

public void getNewEmails(String protocol, String host, String port, String userName, String password) {
    Properties properties = getServerProperties(protocol, host, port);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    session.setDebug(true);

    try {
        Store store = session.getStore(protocol);
        store.connect(userName, password);

        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

        int count = inbox.getMessageCount();
        Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages(1, count);
        for (Message message : messages) {

            Address[] fromAddresses = message.getFrom();
            System.out.println("...................");
            System.out.println("\t From: " + fromAddresses[0].toString());
            System.out.println("\t To: " + parseAddresses(message.getRecipients(RecipientType.TO)));
            System.out.println("\t CC: " + parseAddresses(message.getRecipients(RecipientType.CC)));
            System.out.println("\t Subject: " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println("\t Sent Date:" + message.getSentDate().toString());
            System.out.println(message.getContent());
        }
        inbox.close(false);
        store.close();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
        System.out.println("No provider for protocol: " + protocol);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to  the message store");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private String parseAddresses(Address[] address) {

    String listOfAddress = "";
    if ((address == null) || (address.length < 1))
        return null;
    if (!(address[0] instanceof InternetAddress))
        return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
        InternetAddress internetAddress = (InternetAddress) address[0];
        listOfAddress += internetAddress.getAddress() + ",";
    }
    return listOfAddress;
}
```

When I try to run the above code it hangs on `store.connect(userName, password);`

Below is the link from where I tried the above code http://www.developer.com/java/data/monitoring-email-accounts-imap-in-java.html. 
Here is a link which has no answer for the question 
https://community.oracle.com/message/13244272#13244272

Below is the logs while running with both JDK.

JDK 7 LOGS :

```
    DEBUG:setDebug:

JavaMail version 1.5.0-
b01
DEBUG:

getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", port 993, isSSL false
* OK server ready. Unauthorized Access Prohibited.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4REV1 IDLE AUTH=PLAIN
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, user=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4REV1 IDLE AUTH=PLAIN
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: connection available -- size: 1
A3 SELECT INBOX
```

JDK 8 LOGS :

```
    DEBUG:setDebug:

JavaMail version 1.5.0-
b01
DEBUG:

getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", port 993, isSSL false
* OK server ready. Unauthorized Access Prohibited.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4REV1 IDLE AUTH=PLAIN
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, user=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
```

After the above line it hangs and did not respond.

Comment: @DoNhuVy I have added logs from both the jdk.

Comment: Fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) and upgrade to the [current version of JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).  If that doesn't solve the problem, contact me at javamail_ww@oracle.com for more detailed debugging suggestions; we'll probably need to look at the authentication details, which you don't want to post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
After Bill Shannon comment I tried below configuration and it start working with below configuration with JDK-8.

`<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
 <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
 <version>1.5.5</version>
 </dependency>`
```